# Enable directory listing in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to enable Directory listing in Google Cloud Storage?

I was thinking on having a "domain bucket" and use it to list all the contents, similar to Nginx's `autoindex on` or Apache's `Options +Indexes`.

If I make the bucket public all contents will be listed as a XML, but not like a directory listing.

Comment: On Google Cloud Storage you don't have the concept of "directory", only bucket name or object name. The object.list API method accepts a prefix parameter which can simulate the listing of a directory

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible.

You could perhaps implement such a thing by creating "index" pages in each directory that used JavaScript to query the bucket and render a list of objects, but there's no built-in support for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [s3-bucket-listing](https://github.com/rufuspollock/s3-bucket-listing). It's for Amazon S3 but works with GCS as well.